# Is there a way to convert django-filter result to pdf

Tags: python, django, django-filter, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

I am using Django-filter to filter out data and export to csv table I want to export the same data to pdf but I am having trouble using xhtml2pdf and reportlab

This is what I have tried with xhtml2pdf.

here is the view:

```
def pdfview(request):
    user=User.objects.all()

    govFilter=GovFilter(request.GET, queryset=user)
    user=govFilter.qs

    template=render_to_pdf('staff/pdf_template.html')
    # context={'user':user}
    html=template.render(context)

    response=HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition']='attachment; filename="report.pdf"'
    generate_pdf(html,file_object=response)

    return response
```

this is the error.

```
AttributeError at /pdfview/
'str' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt with `xhtml2pdf`?

Comment: I deleted while hacking my way between reportlab and xhtml2pdf. 
I have nothing now, I just want to start afresh

Comment: well that's too bad, since Django-filter can be used simply to filter a queryset so by overriding the logic that retrieves the elements we would be done.

Comment: Let me try to recreate what I’ve tried by editing the question